# 3.days.ago, 2.hours.from_now etc without Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, numeric, activesupport

Some book mentioned some gem to decorate numbers with `#days`, `#megabytes`, `#minutes` etc. Is this only in ActiveSupport, or is there a smaller gem that provides this functionality for use in (small) non-rails gems?  I want to use this functionality as part of a DSL in a tiny little gem.

Comment: I like this behavior too, and have often wanted to use it in my non-rails ruby projects. Good question...

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's another gem available besides `ActiveSupport`, but it would be really straight-forward to make a small version yourself:

```
class Fixnum
  SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60

  def days
    self * SECONDS_IN_DAY
  end

  def ago
    Time.now - self
  end
end

3.days.ago #=> 2011-06-18 08:45:29 0200
```

`from_now` can be implemented like `ago` but with `+ self` and `weeks`, `hours` etc. like `days` using different constants.

Comment: This seems like it may be the way I end up going, thanks.  I thought that the Numeric thing had started in somebody else's project and that ActiveSupport just merged it into their own source.  I'm probably just imagining it though.

Comment: very nice job!!

Answer (score 9):

[ActiveSupport](http://rubygems.org/gems/activesupport) has this functionality. It was originally part of Rails but can now be used separately.

Comment: This is correct but also note you can no longer just ```require 'activesupport'```. The OP will need to be a little more explicit about what they want to ```require``` from activesupport. If you just want time you can ```require "active_support/core_ext/numeric/time"```

Comment: I don't really want to depend on all of ActiveSupport for this :)  That was sort of what I was trying to avoid.  My Gem is just a single class with about 30 lines of code :P  But thanks for the confirmation :)

Comment: @d11wtq then michael kohl's answer would be the way to go. Just extending the fixnum  class with something like a ```days``` and ```ago``` method.

Comment: its `require 'active_support/all'` nowadays

Answer (score 3):

I found: https://github.com/kylewlacy/timerizer

Comment: Just what I was looking for. Not widely used or mature (most recent release is 0.3.0; 33 stars and 3 forks as I type this), but it _has_ been around a while, and looks to be a drop-in that won't force me to add the ActiveSupport crack pipe to my Hanami project. Thanks.